# Creating a chart in VisualBasic.net which has a Y axis comprising of string values

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, graph, charts

I'd like to create a chart in VB.net which has X and Y values in the form of a string. 
Example below:
[Sorry for the bad drawing, but this is what I'd like it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSdeL.png)

Can anybody help me find the settings to do this?
I can transfer data to a graph but it ends up looking like this:
[This is what my current graph looks like. As you can see, I can't get the Y axis working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVO0y.png)

(also dont worry about the X axis containing the grades, that's just something I need to fix. The grades string() still contains the right data)

This is a sample of my code: (don't worry about delimitegrades(), that just formats data for the grades into 'A', 'B', etc)
Subjects is a string() list.
Grades is an array which contains the data I need to insert. ChrtSubgrade is the chart itself.

```
Public Sub CreateGraph(ByVal name As String, subjects() As String)
    MsgBox("Generating graph for " & name)
    chrtSubgrade.Series.Clear()
    chrtSubgrade.Series.Add("Data")
    chrtSubgrade.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column
    chrtSubgrade.Series(0).YValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String
    chrtSubgrade.Series(0).IsValueShownAsLabel = True


    delimitgrades(subjects)

    For i = 0 To subjects.Count - 2
        chrtSubgrade.Series(0).Points.AddXY(subjects(i), grades(i))
    Next
```

I've breakpointed all the code and the arrays and data transfer is fine so I believe it's just down to how I'm creating the graph.

I can't link the chart to a database since I'm drawing the source data from an XML file.

Thanks very much for any help you might be able to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a new method. Instead of using the VB charting tools I made my own. Here's the code:

```
    Public Sub CreateGraph(ByVal name As String, subjects() As String)
    delimitgrades(subjects) 'collects the info from subjects which contains the grade data and make a new array from it containing only grades
    MsgBox("Generating graph for " & name)
    Dim mygraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(hwnd:=ActiveForm.Handle) 'defines a new graphics set on the Grades window
    Dim axespen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5) 'makes a pen so I can draw the axes
    Dim Xaxisleft As New Point(30, 350) 'defines the left point of the X axis
    Dim Xaxisright As New Point(400, 350) 'defines the right point of the X axis
    Dim Yaxisbottom As New Point(30, 350) 'defines the bottom point of the Y axis
    Dim yaxistop As New Point(30, 80) 'defines the top point of the Y axis

    For i = 0 To 4 'for each possible grade - A* through D
        Dim labelgrade As New Label 'makes a label
        With labelgrade 'with said label
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent 'makes its background colourless
            .AutoSize = True 'resizes the bounding box
            Select Case i 'examines I - the counting variable
                Case Is = 0 ' if its 0
                    .Text = "A*" ' sets the labels text to A*
                    .Location = New Point(2, 100) 'moves it to the right place
                Case Is = 1 'etc
                    .Text = "A"
                    .Location = New Point(2, 140)
                Case Is = 2
                    .Text = "B"
                    .Location = New Point(2, 180)
                Case Is = 3
                    .Text = "C"
                    .Location = New Point(2, 220)
                Case Is = 4
                    .Text = "D"
                    .Location = New Point(2, 260)
            End Select '/etc

        End With
        Controls.Add(labelgrade) 'inserts the label into the form

    Next

    For i = 0 To subjects.Count - 2 'the last part of the subjects array is empty so it counts to the last position containing data
        Dim labelsubject As New Label 'makes  a new label
        Dim labelxoffset As Integer = 30 'defines the variable xoffset which is used to determine where all labels should be placed
        With labelsubject 'with this label
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent 'make the background colourless
            .AutoSize = True 'resize the bounding box
            Select Case i 'examine i
                Case Is = 0 'if this is the first label placed onto the form
                    .Text = subjects(i) 'take the first entry in the subjects array
                    .Location = New Point(30, 355) 'place the label on the X axis in the first position
                Case Else 'otherwise
                    .Text = subjects(i) 'take the right name from the array and make the label reflect this name
                    .Location = New Point(labelxoffset + (i * 70), 365) 'set its location depending on which place it is in the array using xoffset
            End Select
        End With
        Controls.Add(labelsubject) 'add the label to the form
    Next

    'Axes
    mygraphics.DrawLine(axespen, Xaxisleft, Xaxisright) 'create 
    mygraphics.DrawLine(axespen, Yaxisbottom, yaxistop) 'the axes

    'bars
    For i = 0 To grades.Count - 1 'from 0 to the second to last entry in the grades array (this is because of how I formed the grades array. It still works.
        Dim grade As String = grades(i) 'create a temp variable to store the correct entry from the grades array
        Dim gradeindex As Integer = Nothing ' create the index integer, this is used to determine how high the bar should go
        Dim gradepen As New Pen(Color.Green, 50) 'make the pen for the bars
        Dim p1 As New Point(30, 350) 'define point 1 as above the first label
        Dim p2 As New Point 'create point 2
        Dim x As Integer = (58 + (70 * i)) 'create a new xoffset integer
        Dim yoffset As Integer = 348 ' create the yoffset integer. This is to place the bottom point of the bar correctly
        Select Case grade 'examine grade
            Case Is = "A*" 'if its A*
                gradeindex = 100 'the top y coord is 100
                p1 = New Point(x, yoffset) 'p1 is now x, yoffset
                p2 = New Point(x, gradeindex) 'p2 is now x, gradeindex
            Case Is = "A" 'etc
                gradeindex = 140
                p1 = New Point(x, yoffset)
                p2 = New Point(x, gradeindex)
            Case Is = "B"
                gradeindex = 180
                p1 = New Point(x, yoffset)
                p2 = New Point(x, gradeindex)
            Case Is = "C"
                gradeindex = 220
                p1 = New Point(x, yoffset)
                p2 = New Point(x, gradeindex)
                gradepen = New Pen(Color.Orange, 50) 'make the grade pen orange
            Case Is = "D"
                gradeindex = 260
                p1 = New Point(x, yoffset)
                p2 = New Point(x, gradeindex)
                gradepen = New Pen(Color.Red, 50) 'make the grade pen red
        End Select  '/etc
        mygraphics.DrawLine(gradepen, p1, p2) 'draw the line from p1 to p2
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's the output for someone who has the following data: German;A* , Maths;A , French;A* , Bio;C , Bus(business for example);B

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1edXj.png)

Hope this helps anyone else having this issue. Thanks!